# SQLServer and Laravel: Invalid Object Name error

Tags: sql-server, laravel-5

Following code is working if I'm using MySQL. When i switch to MS SQLServer i get error. I have already enabled the pdo sqlsrv driver. My database has a table called *products*, But it is showing invalid object name.

Product.php (Model)

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'sqlsrv';
}
?>
```

database.php

```
'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => env('DB_EXT_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('DB_EXT_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_EXT_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_EXT_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ]
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Product;
use App\Http\Requests;

class APIController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $products = Product::paginate(5);
        return response(array(
            'error' => false,
            'products' =>$products->toArray(),
        ),200);
    }
}
?>
```

Output:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'products'. (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from [products])

Comment: What schema does the `products` table have? You may need to specify that as well (e.g `[dbo].[products]`) if the schema in question is not the database default.

Comment: It is database default only. _dbo.products_

Comment: Run that query *manually* from your code and reference the table as [forge].[dbo].[products] and see if you get the same error. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [forge].[dbo].[products]`

Comment: Are you sure Laravel is connecting to the same database that you're looking at? Do a `dd((new Product)->getConnection()->getName(), config('database.connections.sqlsrv'))` to verify the connection name and the connection details are correct.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm very late in party but this could help to other user.

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent):

> plural name of the class will be used as the table name unless another name is explicitly specified

So in your case, table name `products` is different then model `product`. just add below line into your model:

```
protected $table = 'products';
```

Answer (score 0):

If adding the correct schema doesn't work, it could be a permission issue for your user. I'm guessing you are accessing the database with the "forge" user - does that user have select permission on that table?

You may have to run this to be certain:

```
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.products TO forge
```